# Android IMAPFolder.fetch OutOfMemoryError: what can I do about that?

Tags: android, out-of-memory, jakarta-mail, imap

**EDIT:**

I do not see this OOM error anymore. This was possibly related to some memory leak somewhere else in the app: I found one possible Activity leak: this could be the culprit and **JavaMail has nothing to do with this** activity leak... my mistake.

---

My [simplified mail app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.elementique.messages) is working fine for more than 1 year, but lately, I started to receive some bug report about **[OutOfMemoryError](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/OutOfMemoryError.html)** occurring on **Samsung SM-T530 matissewifi 5.0.2** device (i.e. Galaxy Tab 4 (10.1'',Wi-Fi) ).

**Code excerpt:**

```
    try
    {
        FlagTerm ft = new FlagTerm(new Flags(Flags.Flag.SEEN), false);
        Message[] messages = folder.search(ft);

        folder.fetch(messages, createFetchProfile());

        return messages;
    }
    catch (Throwable th)
    {
        // I got OutOfMemoryError here because of folder.fetch(...):
/*
    java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 1036 byte allocation with 8388608 free bytes and 387MB until OOM; failed due to fragmentation (required continguous free 131072 bytes for a new buffer where largest contiguous free 65536 bytes)

    or even this (with !0! for largest contiguous free bytes value!!!)

    java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 1036 byte allocation with 8388608 free bytes and 385MB until OOM; failed due to fragmentation (required continguous free 131072 bytes for a new buffer where largest contiguous free 0 bytes)

        at com.sun.mail.iap.ByteArray.grow(SourceFile:161)
        at com.sun.mail.iap.ResponseInputStream.readResponse(SourceFile:125)
        at com.sun.mail.iap.Response.(SourceFile:121)
        at com.sun.mail.imap.protocol.IMAPResponse.(SourceFile:66)
        at com.sun.mail.imap.protocol.IMAPProtocol.readResponse(SourceFile:458)
        at com.sun.mail.iap.Protocol.command(SourceFile:414)
        at com.sun.mail.imap.protocol.IMAPProtocol.fetch(SourceFile:2440)
        at com.sun.mail.imap.protocol.IMAPProtocol.fetch(SourceFile:2422)
        at com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPFolder.fetch(SourceFile:1417)
        at <mycode...>
*/
    }
```

fetchprofile is

```
    FetchProfile fetchProfile = new FetchProfile();

    fetchProfile.add(UIDFolder.FetchProfileItem.ENVELOPE);

    // fetch other info to speed up process

    fetchProfile.add(UIDFolder.FetchProfileItem.FLAGS);
    fetchProfile.add(UIDFolder.FetchProfileItem.UID);
    fetchProfile.add(UIDFolder.FetchProfileItem.CONTENT_INFO);
    fetchProfile.add(UIDFolder.FetchProfileItem.SIZE); // not sure about this one
```

I found grow() method source: here it is (quite simple):

```
public void grow(int incr)
{
    byte[] nbuf = new byte[bytes.length + incr];
    System.arraycopy(bytes, 0, nbuf, 0, bytes.length);
    bytes = nbuf;
}
```

**Manifest:**

I already have

```
<application android:largeHeap="true">
```

in AndroidManifest.xml.

**Questions:**

Could this be related to a mail box containing so many email that mail API crash with OOM exception? I only fetch [ENVELOPPE](https://javamail.java.net/nonav/docs/api/javax/mail/FetchProfile.Item.html#ENVELOPE) (and a few other things) , so I suppose this is not the correct explanation.

If, as I think, it's NOT related to the amount of email, what can I do about that?

Also, How should I interpret OOM message with value **0** for largest contiguous bytes!?! (sometimes happens, but not always)

java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 1036 byte allocation with 8388608 free bytes and 385MB until OOM; **failed due to fragmentation (required continguous free 131072 bytes for a new buffer where largest contiguous free *0* bytes)**

Answer (score 0):

Of course you should make sure that you're closing Folders when you're done with them, and not keeping references to Folders or Messages that you're no longer using.  And make sure all the other parts of your application aren't causing memory leaks.

The Folder.fetch response needs to be kept in a single byte array.  You can see how the byte array grows.  Compared to the actual content of messages, the fetch information is usually quite small.  But if you have thousands and thousands of messages, it could become large.  Since you're only looking for unseen messages, it seems unlikely that that's the case.

I don't know what's possible on Android but if you could get a heap dump when this happens and examine it to determine which objects are using all the memory that would be most helpful.

Comment: folder are closed and references are cleaned, I already encountered and fixed such problems at early beginning of project.
About fetching unseen messages envelopes, only 'a lot' could explain the error, which, as you wrote is really unlikely.
Obtaining a dump from a customer device... maybe... I'll try to dig a bit about that.
Thanks for your time :-)

Comment: FYI, an activity leak could have been the reason for this old problem. I fixed this a long time ago, but forget to give feedback here. Now it's done and, for what it's worth, I do not suspect JavaMail to be involved in that anymore. Again, thanks a lot for Javamail!

Comment: oh, and FYI, I am using [JavaMail 1.6.1 for Android](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/Android), but with API level **17** (instead of 19) and it's working fine. I made a few simple changes to backport to level 17. Would you consider doing so in your code?

Comment: API level 17 is 6 years old.  It looks like StandardCharsets and Throwable.addSuppressed are missing, which have a pretty big impact on the code.